# Xamarin Android pm install not working programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin, installation, sh, apk

We have an app that runs on a device that has no user interface. within the Xamarin Android app we have granted the dangerous permissions of READ_EXTERNAL WRITE_EXTERNAL INSTALL_PACKAGE and DELETE_PACKAGE and through adb shell install -r -g C:\installpath\apkupdate.apk it is installed with the proper permissions. So this means the app when executing sh commands should be installing. This is Android 9.  When we run the install it appears to run but the install never happens.  I can tell because I check the version after starting the app and it has not changed. It is the same app as before.  The code runs through with no errors yet it does nothing.  Can someone help me with an example where this works?  I also have done this same install with Android Intents and that doesn't work either.

```
   Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(applicationname);

             if (file.Exists())
             {

                String command;

                command = "pm uninstall com.someappname.app\n";

                string[] commandArray = { "sh", "-c", command };
                var proc = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(commandArray);
                proc.WaitFor();

                command = "pm install /sdcard/appname/download/com.someappname.app\n";

                string[] commandArrayInstall = { "sh", "-c", command };
                proc = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(commandArrayInstall);
                proc.WaitFor();
 }
```

Comment: That would only work if your app is running in a "system user" context, so if your app is signed & bundled with the OEM's cert, you could do it this way.

Comment: what is the OEM's cert is this the device manufacturers cert or signing keystore that we would have to use to archive our app that performs the install?

Comment: You would need access to the OEM's signing cert, something, that unless you are building that phone's firmware, you are unlikely to have access to and yes it would need to be used to sign your app.

Comment: ok that makes sense! we will follow up with the device manufacturer to get this.  thanks for your help SushiHangover!

Comment: I have followed all these steps but I was hoping for some clarification.   I went to the duplicate answer and they say to install to app-priv which I did following these steps.  but it still does not execute the install of the other app which is downloaded to the device then installed with the pm command.  In the below steps I see the apk get placed there but is it actually installed by putting the apk their?  Or after its put their do I execute a adb root install -r -g /system/app-priv/someapk-signed.apk  Below are the steps I did

Comment: which match this method https://www.lynxbee.com/how-to-install-and-uninstall-android-application-as-system-app-priv-app/

Comment: adb push C:\com.someappname-Signed.apk /sdcard  
C:\>adb root
C:\>adb remount
remount succeeded
C:\>adb disable-verity
C:\>adb reboot
C:\>adb root
C:\>adb remount
remount succeeded
C:\>adb root mv /sdcard/com.someappname-Signed.apk /system/priv-app
C:\>adb root chmod 644 /system/priv-app/com.someappname-Signed.apk
C:\>adb root chown -R root /system/priv-app/com.someappname-Signed.apk
C:\>adb root chgrp -R root /system/priv-app/com.someappname-Signed.apk
C:\>adb root
C:\>adb remount
remount succeeded
C:\>adb enable-verity
C:\>adb reboot
C:\>adb root
C:\>adb remount
success

Comment: i guess I am a little confused.  I thought only the app performing the install has to be in priv-app.  This is the app I'd like to run the pm install.  Does this mean the app I want to be installed also needs to be installed originally in priv-app too and obviously both need to be signed with the OEM's keystore and I guess both need the shared.system.uid added to the manifest?

Comment: @SushiHangover I did all of this and it does not work in Android 9.0.  How do you update apps silently in this version of Android. I added android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" to the AndroidManifest. I zipaligned and signed the apk with the proper 509 certificate from the manufacturer.  I installed and moved the app into /system/priv-app/  I have the permissions to DELETE_PACKAGES and INSTALL_PACKAGES and the commands do not install or uninstall the app.  This is not a duplicate as we need a new solution for Android 9 and up.

Comment: Please ask a new question that details what you have done and what does not work in Android 9 vs that it is working in lower API levels (include the `logcat` output with the failures (warning/errors). Thanks

Comment: ok will do.  I found the solution.